# Why do I get "type annotations needed" when using Iterator::collect?

Tags: rust

I want to get a length of a string which I've split:

```rust
fn fn1(my_string: String) -> bool {
    let mut segments = my_string.split(".");
    segments.collect().len() == 55
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:3:14
  |
3 |     segments.collect().len() == 55
  |              ^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `B` declared on the associated function `collect`
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

Previous compiler versions report the error:

```
error[E0619]: the type of this value must be known in this context
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     segments.collect().len() == 55
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On an iterator, [the `collect` method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) can produce many types of collections:

```
fn collect<B>(self) -> B
where
    B: FromIterator<Self::Item>,
```

Types that implement `FromIterator` include `Vec`, `String` and [many more](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#implementors). Because there are so many possibilities, something needs to constrain the result type. You can specify the type with something like `.collect::<Vec<_>>()` or `let something: Vec<_> = some_iter.collect()`.

Until the type is known, you cannot call the method `len()` because it's impossible to know if an unknown type has a specific method.

---

If you’re purely wanting to find out how many items there are in an iterator, use [`Iterator.count()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count); creating a vector for the purpose is rather inefficient.