# Rust chunks and joins

Tags: rust

Is there a more elegant way of chunking an array and then joining it?

```
fn main() {
    let size = 4;
    let buffer = vec![0; size * size];

    let pbm = format!(
        "P4\n{} {}\n{}",
        size,
        size,
        buffer
            .chunks(size)
            .map(|chunk| chunk
                .into_iter()
                .map(|x| x.to_string())
                .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                .join(" "))
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join("\n")
    );

    println!("{:?}", pbm);
}
```

Why do I have to precise type to `collect`? Shouldn't it find it out by at what `map` returns?

Comment: You can collect into any type that implements `FromIterator`. So not precising the type is ambiguous.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30972047/1233251

Comment: Both times that you use `collect`, you then call `join()`. Rust doesn't know which implementation of `join` you mean until it knows the type returned by `collect`.

Comment: Note that in the general case, if you want to display your matrix, you'd better define a struct implementing Display and wrapping your buffer rather than use intermediate strings. You can do the whole without any String.

Comment: Also relevant: [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941851/whats-an-idiomatic-way-to-print-an-iterator-separated-by-spaces-in-rust)

Comment: @DenysSéguret could you please create an answer and illustrate your proposal?

Comment: @LukeSkywalker I can't as the question is closed

Comment: @LukeSkywalker Here's the kind of solution I had in mind: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=309ec420b04925f9f84bd03a9e25661f