# How can I automatically apply the From trait to convert to a generic argument type when invoking a function?

Tags: rust

Explicitly using `String::from` in the following code works, but how can I make it automatically use `From<OsStringWrap<'a>>` trait without explicitly using `String::from`?

```rust
use serde::Serialize; // 1.0.115

struct OsStringWrap<'a>(&'a std::ffi::OsString);
impl<'a> From<OsStringWrap<'a>> for String {
    fn from(s: OsStringWrap) -> String {
        s.0.to_string_lossy().to_string()
    }
}

pub fn insert<T: Serialize + ?Sized, S: Into<String>>(_key: S, _value: &T) {}

fn main() {
    for (key, value) in std::env::vars_os() {
        // HOW-TO: auto use From<OsStringWrap<'a>> trait
        // without explicit `String::from` like below?
        /*
            insert(OsStringWrap(&key), &OsStringWrap(&value))
        */

        // below using `String::from` to make it explicitly
        // but want to find a way to make it shorter
        insert(OsStringWrap(&key), &String::from(OsStringWrap(&value)))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5032393e8aea216f0f4d838b0f1e4297), and the `insert` method is a real case from [tera](https://docs.rs/tera/1.5.0/tera/struct.Context.html#method.insert)

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423). This also applied for `OsString` / `&OsStr`.

Comment: Why does this code use `Serialize`? That doesn't seem important to the question.

Comment: @Shepmaster the `insert` method is a real case from [tera](https://docs.rs/tera/1.5.0/tera/struct.Context.html#method.insert)

Comment: So you have a function that requests a `T: Serialize`... and rather than implementing `Serialize` for `OsStringWrap` you are converting it to a `String` first... and you want the `String`-conversion to be automatic? Seems roundabout. Why not just implement `Serialize`?

Answer (score 1):

Your request as currently phrased is impossible. Your `insert` function accepts a generic type, so nothing exists to tell the compiler what type should be converted to. This tiny example is equivalent:

```rust
fn demo<T>(_: T) {}

fn main() {
    demo(true.into());
}
```

Since the compiler can not know what concrete type to pick to convert to, the programmer **must** specify it.

You could potentially change your function to accept anything that can be turned into a `String` (e.g. `T: Into<String>`) or be referenced as a `&str` (e.g. `T: AsRef<str>`).

See also:

- [Type must be known in this context when using Iterator::collect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30972047/155423)
- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)